# Skydome deluxe and sun movement

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have tried adopting the following code to my school project:

https://github.com/kosua20/opengl-skydome

But I do not understand the sun_pos uniform value. However I set it, the sun moves really weird, and seem to slow down at times. It says the value is the "sun's position in world space", but I do not really see that it is. I need help understanding how I should be able to manipulate this value to make the sun move realistically across the sky.

Comment: About "sun's position in world space", what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Well, what is that position supposed to be? If I have a 3d vector that I set to 0.0 and then increment each component by 0.001 each frame, the sun does not move at all. I thought that if I increment Y from 0 to 1 with 0.001 each frame, the sun would actually move, but it does not. Therefore, I am suspecting that this is not position at all, but rather some form of weird rotation that I cannot grasp.

Comment: I'm not going to dig into that code, but regarding the Sun. It's too far, you can consider it's light-cone as a light-cylinder. And if you want to draw it as a circle then its position is better expressed in polar-system coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the vertex shader, the `sun_pos` is being normalized.

```
sun_norm = normalize(sun_pos);
```

That means, no matter how much you increase the Y position, it's the same vector.

In this case, it makes more sense to adjust the sun direction using a pair of Euler angles (heading, pitch).

You can convert the two Euler angles to a direction vector using the following formula.

```
x = cos(pitch) * cos(heading)
y = sin(pitch)
z = cos(pitch) * sin(heading)
```